# A property of proportions: if $a/b=c/d$, then $(ma+nb)/(pa+qb)$ is equal to $ (mc+nd)/(pc+qd)$

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

If $\large\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ how we can obtain $\displaystyle{\frac{ma+nb}{pa+qb}=\frac{mc+nd}{pc+qd}}$?

I can get $\large\frac{ma}{qb}=\frac{mc}{qd}$ and $\large\frac{nb}{pa}=\frac{nd}{pc}$ , now

If we have $\large\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ and $\large\frac{e}{f}=\frac{g}{h}$ is true that $\large\frac{a+e}{b+f}=\frac{c+g}{d+h}$ , I tried a particular solution and is not true at least for most cases,but for the above expression is true so how do I get there?can you help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:$$\frac{ma+nb}{pa+qb}=\frac{m\frac{a}{b}+n}{p\frac{a}{b}+q}$$

Comment: ?I follow up your hint but I don't know what to do,I have so far (m(a/b)+n)/(p(a/b)+q)=(m(c/d)+n)/(p(c/d)+q) what to do next?or is this way I suppose to go?

Comment: OK I think I got it,I substitute x=a/b=c/d and the resulting equation holds true, therefore I start with that to get my expression, thank you

Comment: This is the way you are supposed to go. Notice that: $\frac{m\frac{c}{d}+n}{p\frac{c}{d}+q}=\frac{\frac{mc+dn}{d}}{\frac{pc+qd}{d}}= \frac{mc+nd}{pc+dq}$.

Comment: Yes I understand that , thank you again

Comment: My apologies. Just wanted to clarify. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Follows immediately by $\rm\color{#c00}{M} =$ [mediant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1817456/242), or by [denominator linearity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4421745/242) ("Or" below)

$x = \dfrac{\color{c00}a}{\color{c00}c}= \dfrac{\color{c00}b}{\color{c00}d}\,\Rightarrow\, x = \dfrac{m\color{c00}a}{m\color{c00}c} = \dfrac{n\color{c00}b}{n\color{c00}d}\,\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{M}}\Rightarrow\, x = \dfrac{ma\!+\!nb}{mc\!+\!nd}\ \left[ = \dfrac{pa\!+\!qb}{pc\!+\!qd}\,\ \rm similarly\right]$

---

$\begin{align}
{\bf Or}\qquad\qquad  m\, &\left[cx = a\right]\\
+\ \ n\,&\left[dx = b\right]\\
\hline
\Longrightarrow \ \ (mc\!+\!nd)\,x\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! &\quad\ \ = ma\!+\!nd \end{align}$

Comment: OP = diagonal swap of above equality ie. $\,\dfrac{I}{\color{#0a0}J} = \dfrac{\color{#c00}{I'}}{J'}\!\iff \dfrac{I}{\color{#c00}{I'}}=\dfrac{\color{#0a0}J}{J'}\ \ $