# Does $D(n)$ always depend on $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))$ when $\sigma(N)=aN+b$, $N=xn$, and $n$ is a square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Does $D(n)$ always depend on $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))$ when $\sigma(N)=aN+b$, $N=xn$, and $n$ is a square (with $\gcd(x,n)=1$)?

Here, $\sigma$ is the sum of divisors and $D(n) := 2n - \sigma(n)$ is the deficiency of $n$.

**Copied from the comments**
For odd $N$ satisfying $\sigma(N)=2N$, we have $N=xn$ where $n$ is a square and $\gcd(x,n)=1$.  In this case, it is known that $D(n)$ is a function (more accurately, a multiple) of $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))$.

Comment: For odd $N$ satisfying $\sigma(N)=2N$, we have $N=xn$ where  $n$ is a square and $\gcd(x,n)=1$. In this case, it is known that $D(n)$ is a function (more accurately, a multiple) of $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))$.

Comment: More precisely:  If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then
$$D(n^2) = \sigma(q^{k-1})\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)).$$

Comment: For the case when $I(m) = \frac{\sigma(m)}{m} = \frac{p+2}{p}$ (where $p$ is an odd prime), it is known that $D(m) = (p - 2)\cdot\gcd(m,\sigma(m))$.  (See this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090850) for more information.)