# Bounds for the abundancy index of divisors of odd perfect numbers in terms of the deficiency function

Tags: number-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

*Motivation*

Let $x, y$ and $z$ be positive integers.

Denote the sum of divisors of $x$ by $\sigma(x)$.  Also, denote the deficiency of $y$ by $D(y)=2y-\sigma(y)$.  Lastly, denote the abundancy index of $z$ by $I(z)=\sigma(z)/z$.

Let $N = p^k m^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special/Euler prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  Since $p^k$ and $m^2$ are proper factors of the perfect number $N = p^k m^2$, then $p^k$ and $m^2$ are deficient.

From the [referenced paper](https://www.mililink.com/issue_content.php?id=62&iId=334&vol=8&is=1&mon=February&yer=2018&pg=1-9), and using the facts that $D(p^k) > 1$ and $D(m^2) > 1$, we have the bounds
$$\frac{2p^k}{p^k + D(p^k)} < I(p^k) < \frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)}$$
and
$$\frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)} < I(m^2) < \frac{2m^2 + D(m^2)}{m^2 + D(m^2)}$$
from which we obtain
$$\frac{4p^k m^2}{(p^k + D(p^k))(m^2 + D(m^2))} < I(p^k)I(m^2) = 2 < \frac{(2p^k + D(p^k))(2m^2 + D(m^2))}{(p^k + D(p^k))(m^2 + D(m^2))}.$$

The LHS of the last inequality yields
$$p^k m^2 < p^k D(m^2) + m^2 D(p^k) + D(p^k)D(m^2),$$
while the RHS results to
$$D(p^k) D(m^2) < 2p^k m^2.$$

Dividing throughout the last two inequalities by $p^k m^2$, we get
$$1 < \frac{D(p^k)}{p^k} + \frac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \frac{D(p^k)}{p^k}\cdot\frac{D(m^2)}{m^2}$$ 
$$= \bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg) + \bigg(2 - I(m^2)\bigg) + \bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg)\bigg(2 - I(m^2)\bigg)$$
$$= 4 - \bigg(I(p^k) + I(m^2)\bigg) + 6 - 2\bigg(I(p^k) + I(m^2)\bigg)$$
$$= 10 - 3\bigg(I(p^k) + I(m^2)\bigg) \implies I(p^k) + I(m^2) < 3$$
and
$$6 - 2\bigg(I(p^k) + I(m^2)\bigg) = \bigg(2 - I(p^k)\bigg)\bigg(2 - I(m^2)\bigg) = \frac{D(p^k)}{p^k}\cdot\frac{D(m^2)}{m^2} < 2$$ 
$$\implies 2 < I(p^k) + I(m^2)$$

Since it is known [(Corollary 10, page 5)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf) that
$$\frac{57}{20} < I(p^k) + I(m^2) < 3$$
it is my impression that:

> > **(1)** The LHS of
> >     $$\frac{2n}{n + D(n)} < I(n) < \frac{2n + D(n)}{n + D(n)}$$
> >     (for $D(n) > 1$) is best-possible.
> >
> > **(2)** The RHS of
> >     $$\frac{2n}{n + D(n)} < I(n) < \frac{2n + D(n)}{n + D(n)}$$
> >     (for $D(n) > 1$) is *not* best-possible.

*Question*

**Are my impressions correct?**

*Reference*

Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris, [A Criterion for Deficient Numbers Using the Abundancy Index and Deficiency Functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6767), arXiv:1308.6767 [math.NT], 2013-2016; Journal for Algebra and Number Theory Academia, Volume 8, Issue 1 (February 2018), 1-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3621579/78967) proves that

$$\frac{2n}{n+D(n)}<\frac{(2a+2)n−aD(n)}{(a+1)n+D(n)}<I(n)\tag3$$

$$I(n)\lt\frac{(2b+4)n-bD(n)}{(b+2)n+D(n)}\lt \frac{2n+D(n)}{n+D(n)}\tag4$$

hold for any $a>0,b\gt -1$.

Under the condition that $D(n)\gt 1$, we have

$$\begin{align}(3)&\iff \frac{2n}{n+D}<\frac{(2a+2)n−aD}{(a+1)n+D}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{(2a+2)n−aD}{(a+1)n+D}<\frac{2n-D}{n}
\\\\&\iff 2n(an+n+D)\lt (2an+2n-aD)(n+D)\quad\text{and}
\\&\qquad\qquad n(2an+2n-aD)\lt (2n-D)(an+n+D) 
\\\\&\iff D(n)\lt n
\\\\&\iff \sigma(n)\gt n\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}(4)&\iff \frac{2n-D}{n}\lt\frac{(2b+4)n-bD}{(b+2)n+D}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{(2b+4)n-bD}{(b+2)n+D}\lt \frac{2n+D}{n+D}
\\\\&\iff (2n-D)(bn+2n+D)\lt n(2bn+4n-bD)\quad\text{and}
\\&\qquad\qquad (2bn+4n-bD)(n+D)\lt (2n+D)(bn+2n+D)
\\\\&\iff D(n)\gt 0\end{align}$$

It follows that both $(3)$ and $(4)$ hold under the condition that $D(n)\gt 1$.

Therefore, the answer is as follows :

- The impression (1) is not correct.
- The impression (2) is correct.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: I tried applying your improved lower bound, @mathlove, with $a=2$, to $p^k$ and $m^2$, respectively, where $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

I am still getting
$$I(p^k) + I(m^2) < 3$$
as the final inequality after careful simplification.

I think, in that sense, I can say that my original lower bound is *best-possible*.

Comment: Any way, gladly accepting your answer now, @mathlove!  =)