# Bounds for the abundancy index of divisors of odd perfect numbers in terms of the deficiency function - Part II

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

This post is an offshoot of this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364154).

*Motivation*

Let $x, y$ and $z$ be positive integers.

Denote the sum of divisors of $x$ by $\sigma(x)$.  Also, denote the deficiency of $y$ by $D(y)=2y-\sigma(y)$.  Lastly, denote the abundancy index of $z$ by $I(z)=\sigma(z)/z$.

Let $N = p^k m^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special/Euler prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  Since $p^k$ and $m^2$ are proper factors of the perfect number $N = p^k m^2$, then $p^k$ and $m^2$ are deficient.

From the [referenced paper](https://www.mililink.com/issue_content.php?id=62&iId=334&vol=8&is=1&mon=February&yer=2018&pg=1-9), and using the facts that $D(p^k) > 1$ and $D(m^2) > 1$, we have the bounds
$$\frac{2p^k}{p^k + D(p^k)} < I(p^k) < \frac{2p^k + D(p^k)}{p^k + D(p^k)}$$
and
$$\frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)} < I(m^2) < \frac{2m^2 + D(m^2)}{m^2 + D(m^2)}$$
from which we obtain
$$\frac{4p^k m^2}{(p^k + D(p^k))(m^2 + D(m^2))} < I(p^k)I(m^2) = 2 < \frac{(2p^k + D(p^k))(2m^2 + D(m^2))}{(p^k + D(p^k))(m^2 + D(m^2))}.$$

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3663527/28816) by [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967) improves these bounds to

$$\frac{2n}{n+D(n)}<\frac{(2a+2)n−aD(n)}{(a+1)n+D(n)}<I(n) \tag{1}$$

$$I(n)\lt\frac{(2b+4)n-bD(n)}{(b+2)n+D(n)}\lt \frac{2n+D(n)}{n+D(n)}\tag{2},$$

(where it is implicit that $D(n)>1$) and also shows that it holds for any $a>0,b\gt -1$.

So initially, I have the inequalities
$$\dfrac{(2c + 2)p^k - cD(p^k)}{(c + 1)p^k + D(p^k)} < I(p^k) < \dfrac{(2d + 4)p^k - dD(p^k)}{(d + 2)p^k + D(p^k)}$$
$$\dfrac{(2e + 2)m^2 - eD(m^2)}{(e + 1)m^2 + D(m^2)} < I(m^2) < \dfrac{(2f + 4)m^2 - fD(m^2)}{(f + 2)m^2 + D(m^2)}.$$

Per mathlove's result, these inequalities hold for **any** $c > 0$, $e > 0$, $d > -1$, and $f > -1$.  In particular, the inequalities hold for $c = d = e = f = 1$.

We then obtain
$$\dfrac{(4p^k - D(p^k))(4m^2 - D(m^2))}{(2p^k + D(p^k)(2m^2 + D(m^2))} < I(p^k)I(m^2) = 2 < \dfrac{(6p^k - D(p^k))(6m^2 - D(m^2))}{(3p^k + D(p^k))(3m^2 + D(m^2))}. \tag3$$

---

Let us focus on the **LHS** of Inequality **(3)** first.  We get
$$(4p^k - D(p^k))(4m^2 - D(m^2)) < 2(2p^k + D(p^k)(2m^2 + D(m^2))$$
$$4p^k m^2 + 2p^k \sigma(m^2) + 2m^2 \sigma(p^k) + \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2) = (2p^k + \sigma(p^k))(2m^2 + \sigma(m^2)) < 2(4p^k - \sigma(p^k))(4m^2 - \sigma(m^2)) = 32p^k m^2 - 8p^k \sigma(m^2) - 8m^2 \sigma(p^k) + 2\sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2),$$
an inequality which is equivalent to
$$30 p^k m^2 = 28p^k m^2 + \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2) > 10 p^k \sigma(m^2) + 10 m^2 \sigma(p^k),$$
whence by dividing throughout by $10 p^k m^2$, we obtain the final estimate
$$I(m^2) + I(p^k) < 3,$$
which agrees with (and does not improve on) known computations.

---

Now, let us focus on the **RHS** of Inequality **(3)**.  We derive
$$2(5p^k - \sigma(p^k))(5m^2 - \sigma(m^2)) = 2(3p^k + D(p^k))(3m^2 + D(m^2)) < (6p^k - D(p^k))(6m^2 - D(m^2)) = (4p^k + \sigma(p^k))(4m^2 + \sigma(m^2))$$
$$2(25p^k m^2 - 5p^k \sigma(m^2) - 5m^2 \sigma(p^k) + \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)) < 16p^k m^2 + 4p^k \sigma(m^2) + 4m^2 \sigma(p^k) + \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)$$
$$36p^k m^2 = 34p^k m^2 + \sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2) < 14p^k \sigma(m^2) + 14m^2 \sigma(p^k).$$
Dividing throughout the last inequality by $14 p^k m^2$, we obtain
$$\dfrac{18}{7} = \dfrac{36}{14} < I(m^2) + I(p^k),$$
a lower bound which *does not improve* on the previously known
$$\dfrac{57}{20} < I(m^2) + I(p^k).$$

*Questions*

> **(1)** Is there a $4$-tuple $(c,d,e,f)$ such that the inequalities for $I(p^k)$ and $I(m^2)$ (due to mathlove) result to (an) improved lower (and/or upper) bound(s) for $I(p^k) + I(m^2)$?

> **(2)** If the answer to *Question* **(1)** is *NO*, can you explain why?

*Reference*

Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris, [A Criterion for Deficient Numbers Using the Abundancy Index and Deficiency Functions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6767), arXiv:1308.6767 [math.NT], 2013-2016; Journal for Algebra and Number Theory Academia, Volume 8, Issue 1 (February 2018), 1-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\dfrac{(2c + 2)p^k - cD(p^k)}{(c + 1)p^k + D(p^k)} < I(p^k) < \dfrac{(2d + 4)p^k - dD(p^k)}{(d + 2)p^k + D(p^k)}$$
and
$$\dfrac{(2e + 2)m^2 - eD(m^2)}{(e + 1)m^2 + D(m^2)} < I(m^2) < \dfrac{(2f + 4)m^2 - fD(m^2)}{(f + 2)m^2 + D(m^2)}$$
where $c > 0,e > 0,d > -1$ and $f > -1$.

Therefore, we get
$$\dfrac{(2c + 2)p^k - cD(p^k)}{(c + 1)p^k + D(p^k)}\cdot\dfrac{(2e + 2)m^2 - eD(m^2)}{(e + 1)m^2 + D(m^2)}\lt I(p^k)I(m^2)=2\lt \dfrac{(2d + 4)p^k - dD(p^k)}{(d + 2)p^k + D(p^k)}\cdot\dfrac{(2f + 4)m^2 - fD(m^2)}{(f + 2)m^2 + D(m^2)}$$

---

From the inequality on the left, we obtain
$$\bigg((2c + 2)p^k - cD(p^k)\bigg)\bigg((2e + 2)m^2 - eD(m^2)\bigg)\lt 2\bigg((c + 1)p^k + D(p^k)\bigg)\bigg((e + 1)m^2 + D(m^2)\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$\bigg(2p^k +c\sigma(p^k)\bigg)\bigg(2m^2 +e\sigma(m^2)\bigg)\lt 2\bigg((c+3)p^k -\sigma(p^k)\bigg)\bigg((e + 3)m^2-\sigma(m^2)\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$\bigg(2(c+3)(e+3)-4+2(2-ec)\bigg)p^km^2=\bigg(2(c+3)(e+3)-4\bigg)p^km^2+\bigg(2-ec\bigg)\sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)\gt \bigg(2c+6+2e\bigg)p^k\sigma(m^2)+\bigg(2e+6+2c\bigg)m^2\sigma(p^k)$$
Dividing the both sides by $(2c+2e+6)p^km^2$ gives
$$I(m^2)+I(p^k)\lt 3$$

---

From the inequality on the right
$$2\lt \dfrac{(2d + 4)p^k - dD(p^k)}{(d + 2)p^k + D(p^k)}\cdot\dfrac{(2f + 4)m^2 - fD(m^2)}{(f + 2)m^2 + D(m^2)}$$
we obtain
$$2\bigg((d + 2)p^k + D(p^k)\bigg)\bigg((f + 2)m^2 + D(m^2)\bigg)\lt \bigg((2d + 4)p^k - dD(p^k)\bigg)\bigg((2f + 4)m^2 - fD(m^2)\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$2\bigg((d + 4)p^k -\sigma(p^k)\bigg)\bigg((f + 4)m^2 -\sigma(m^2)\bigg)\lt \bigg(4p^k +d\sigma(p^k)\bigg)\bigg(4m^2 +f\sigma(m^2)\bigg)$$
i.e.
$$\bigg(2(d+4)(f+4)-16+2(2-df)\bigg)p^km^2\lt \bigg(2(d+4)+4f\bigg)p^k\sigma(m^2)+\bigg(2(f+4)+4d\bigg)m^2\sigma(p^k)$$
Dividing the both sides by $p^km^2$ gives
$$4d+4f+10\lt (d+4+2f)I(m^2)+(f+4+2d)I(p^k)$$

Now,
$d+4+2f=f+4+2d$ holds if and only if $f=d$ for which we have
$$I(m^2)+I(p^k)\gt \frac{8d+10}{3d+4}$$
Let $f(d)=\dfrac{8d+10}{3d+4}$. Then, $f'(d)=\dfrac{2}{(3d+4)^2}\gt 0$, so we get
$$I(m^2)+I(p^k)\gt \lim_{d\to\infty}f(d)=\color{red}{\frac 83}$$
which is larger than $\dfrac{18}{7}$, but is still smaller than $\dfrac{57}{20}$.

Comment: Hi there, @mathlove.  I had to un-accept your answer.  $f(d) = (8d + 10)/(3d + 4)$ implies $f'(d) > 0$, which means that $f$ is an increasing function of $d$.  Hence, surely you will agree that
$$I(m^2) + I(p^k) > f(d) \geq f(1) = \dfrac{18}{7},$$
and **not**
$$I(m^2) + I(p^k) > \lim_{d \rightarrow \infty}{f(d)} = \dfrac{8}{3}?$$

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Note that for **any** $d\gt -1$, $I(m^2)+I(p^k)\gt f(d)$ holds. This means that we have $I(m^2)+I(p^k)\gt f(100)$, $I(m^2)+I(p^k)\gt f(1000)$ and $I(m^2)+I(p^k)\gt \displaystyle\lim_{d\to\infty}f(d)=\dfrac 83$.