# Denominators of fractions are closed under gcd (vector gcds)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, sums-of-squares

Let $N$ be odd and $N = a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$, where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$ and WLOG let $a, c$ be odd, $b, d$ be even, $a > c$, and $b < d$. Prove that $\frac{a-c}{k}=\frac{d+b}{n}$.

I first began the proof my showing that $k$ and $n$ are positive integers.

Let $k= \gcd(a -c, d-b)$ and $n= \gcd(a + c, d + b)$. If $a$ and $c$ are both odd, then $a\pm c$ is even. Similarly, if $d$ and $b$ are both even, then $b\pm d$ is also even. Thus, $k$ and $n$ are also both even.

Now I wish to show that  $\frac{a-c}{k}=\frac{d+b}{n}$.

I first tried to use the fact that $N = a^2 + b^2 = c^2 + d^2$.
$$
\begin{align*}
a^2 + b^2 &= c^2 + d^2\\
a^2 -c^2 &= d^2-b^2\\
(a+c)(a-c)&=(d+b)(d-b)\\
\end{align*}
$$

This seems like I'm getting close but I can't quite see how to finish it. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an instance of the basic fact that possible denominators for a fraction are closed under gcd, i.e. $ $ if a fraction $\,q\,$ is writable with denom's $\,b_1$ and $\,b_2$ then it is writable with denom $\,\gcd(b_1,b_2).\,$
It's a $1$ line $\rm\color{#90f}{Proof}$ from your $\color{#c00}{\rm equality},\:\!$ via  $\rm\color{#0a0}{DL}$ = [gcd Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242) $\,x(y,z)\! =\! (xy,xz)$

$\!\begin{align} {\bf Your\ case}\!:\,\ \  &\ 0 < q\, =\, {\small \color{#c00}{\frac{a\!-\!c}{d\!+\!b}\ =\ \dfrac{d\!-\!b}{a\!+\!c}}} \Rightarrow\ q ={\small \dfrac{(a\!-\!c,d\!-\!b)}{(d\!+\!b,a\!+\!c)} = \frac{k}n,}\ \ \ \text{follows by}\\[.5em]
{\bf Lemma}\!:\qquad  &\ 0\,<\, q\, =\, \color{#c00}{\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}\ =\ \dfrac{a_2}{b_2}}\ \ \Rightarrow\ q = \dfrac{(a_1,a_2)}{(b_1,b_2)},\ \ \ \   (x,y) :=\gcd(x,y)\\[.5em]
{\color{#90f}{\bf Pf\!\!:}}\,\ \ \color{#e80}{a_1}(b_1,b_2) &\!\overset{\rm\color{#0a0}{DL_{\phantom{'}\!}}}= (a_1 b_1, \color{#c00}{a_1 b_2}) = (a_1 b_1,\color{#c00}{a_2 b_1}) \overset{\rm\color{#0a0}{DL_{\phantom{'}\!}}}= \color{#e80}{b_1} (a_1,a_2)\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#e80}{\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}}=\dfrac{(a_1,a_2)}{(b_1,b_2)}\\[.6em]
{\bf Example}\!:\qquad\!\!\! &\ \qquad\ q = \dfrac{133}{247} = \dfrac{119}{221}\, \Rightarrow\ q = \dfrac{(133,119)}{(247,221)} = \dfrac{7}{13}\end{align}\qquad$

---

**Remark** $ $ Though - as usual - we can also give a proof of the Lemma via prime factorizations, the above proof has the advantage that it generalizes more widely since it requires much less - only a *distributive law*. Namely, if we eliminate use of fractions then the Lemma amounts to

$$a_1b_2 = b_1 a_2\ \Rightarrow\ a_1(b_1,b_2) = b_1(a_1,a_2)\qquad$$

This inference proof works for many other algebraic systems enjoying distributivity, e.g. we can read $\:\!(x,y)\:\!$ as an ideal instead of a gcd and it remains true. More simply, we can read $\:\!(x,y)\:\!$ as $\,x+y\,$ and then the proof shows that the [mediant](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4122676/242) has the same value as two equal fractions, i.e.

$$q\, =\, \color{c00}{\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}\ =\ \dfrac{a_2}{b_2}}\  \Rightarrow\ q = \dfrac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\!\!$$

and similarly for the (multi-)linear form $\,(x,y):= jx+ky$.

The lemma is viewable as a *Euclidean descent* on equivalent fractions - which often proves handy, e.g. it can be used to efficiently implement the extended Euclidean algorithm in (modular) *fraction form*, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242).

As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242), we can also view the Lemma in  "order" language, since the least denom of a fraction is its *order* in $\,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z.\,$ Then said denominator descent is: $ $ if $\,m,n\,$ are denom's of $\,q\,$ then so too is their gcd $\:\!(n,m),\:\!$ which is an *additive* analog of the following well-known theorem
$${\rm if}\ \ q^m\! = 1 = q^n\ \ {\rm then}\ \ q^{(m,n)}=1,\ \ {\rm by}\ \  {\rm ord}(q)\mid m,n\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm ord}(q)\mid (m,n)\qquad$$

These ideas are abstracted when studying
pertinent algebraic structures: $ $ *ideals* and *modules* (viz. [order ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22order+ideals%22) and  [denominator ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+%22denominator+ideals%22)), or [annihilator ideals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(ring_theory)) (in PIDs).

Comment: To those wondering why this answer got so many downvotes please refer to [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34738/242) posted by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$k = \gcd(a - c, d - b) \; \; \to \; \; a - c = ke, \; d - b = kf, \; \gcd(e, f) = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$n = \gcd(a + c, d + b) \; \; \to \; \; a + c = ng, \; d + b = nh, \; \gcd(g, h) = 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Using \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A} with your factorization gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(a + c)(a - c) & = (d + b)(d - b) \\
(ng)(ke) & = (nh)(kf) \\
ge & = hf
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

With \eqref{eq1A} giving $\gcd(e,f) = 1$, then \eqref{eq3A} shows that

$$f \mid g \; \; \to \; \; g = sf, \; s \ge 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Similarly, since $\gcd(g,h) = 1$ from \eqref{eq2A}, then

$$h \mid e \; \to \; e = th, \; t \ge 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Thus, \eqref{eq3A} becomes

$$(sf)(th) = hf \; \; \to \; \; st = 1 \; \; \to \; \; s = t = 1 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Therefore, using \eqref{eq1A}, \eqref{eq2A}, \eqref{eq5A} and \eqref{eq6A}, we have that

$$e = h \; \; \to \; \; \frac{a - c}{k} = \frac{d + b}{n} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that those sums and differences are there to muddy the waters.

Let's write $A=a+c$, $C=A-c$, $D=d+b$ and $B=d-b$. As you observed, the given equation $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ is equivalent to
$$AC=DB.\qquad(*)$$
And the claim is that $(*)$ implies
$$\frac C{\gcd(B,C)}=\frac{D}{\gcd(A,D)}.\qquad(\dagger)$$

It is simple to do this one prime factor at a time. So let $p$ be a prime number, and assume that in the prime factorizations we have $p^n$ appearing in $A$, $p^m$ appearing in $C$, $p^r$ in $D$ and $p^s$ in $B$. By uniqueness of factorization $(*)$ implies that
$$n+m=r+s.\qquad(**)$$
The claim $(\dagger)$ is then translated to
$$
m-\min\{m,s\}=r-\min\{r,n\}.\qquad(\dagger\dagger)
$$
This is now easy to see. From $(**)$ it follows that $m-s=r-n$. Hence $\min\{m,s\}=s$ if and only if $\min\{r,n\}=m$ in which case the claim is exactly $m-s=r-n$. In the complementary case $\min\{m,s\}=m$ and $\min\{r,n\}=r$ the claim $(\dagger\dagger)$ reads $0=0$.

Comment: The endgame reflects the analogy between the $\gcd$, $\mathrm{lcm}$ and $\min$, $\max$. The product of the former pair being equal to the actual product, and the sum of the latter pair being equal to the actual sum.

Comment: There were a number of obvious typos. Hopefully fixed now.

Comment: In reply to your prior comment, I reorganized and expanded my answer to explain some advantages of using distributivity, e.g. it yields a proof that also works for ideals, which can't be done as above.