# Deriving a CRT formula for noncoprime moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

The German Wikipedia page on the Chinese Remainder Theorem [states the following](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinesischer_Restsatz#Direktes_L%C3%B6sen_von_simultanen_Kongruenzen_ganzer_Zahlen)

> Given are the two simultaneous congruences:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & x \equiv a \quad(\bmod n) \\
> & x \equiv b \quad(\bmod m)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> If these are solvable, that is $a \equiv b \quad(\bmod d)$, then they are equivalent to
> $$
> x \equiv a-y n \frac{a-b}{d} \pmod{\frac{n m}{d}}
> $$
> with
> $$
> d=\operatorname{gcd}(n, m)=y n+z m .
> $$
> This also works with non-divisor numbers $n$ and $m$ and thus provides a significant simplification in solving simultaneous congruences.

I wanted to derive/proof this statement and you can directly see that $nm/d=\operatorname{lcm} nm$. I translated the congruences
$$
x-a=tn
$$
$$
x-b=km
$$
$$
a-b=sd
$$
And tried to work backwards
$$
x-a+yn\frac{a-b}{d} = \frac{nm}{d}p
$$
which is, after dividing by $n$
$$
t+y\frac{a-b}{d} = \frac{m}{d}p
$$
and furthermore
$$
(t+ys)d=mp
$$
for $k,s,t,p\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is not helpful and leads to nothing. Maybe anyone has an idea or a hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That follows immediately from the  [General CRT formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) below (chase the link for a proof)  $$\ \ x\equiv  a + n\left[\dfrac{(b-a)/d}{\color{#c00}{n/d}} \bmod m/d\right]\pmod{mn/d}$$  since $\,\color{#c00}{(n/d)^{-1}}\equiv y\pmod{\!m/d},\, $ by $\,y\,\color{#c00}{n/d} + z\,m/d = 1,\, $  by dividing Bezout by $\:\!d$.

---

**Alternatively** scaling by $m,n$ (to equalize moduli) yields an equivalent system $\!\bmod mn,\,$which Hermite reduces to an *equivalent*  single congruence  (*equiv.* by determinant $= \color{#0a0}{zm\!+\!yn} = d\neq 0)$

$$\begin{align} mx&\equiv ma\!\!\pmod{\!mn}\\ 
                nx&\equiv\  nb\!\!\!\:\pmod{\!mn}\end{align}\!\color{#c00}
\iff dx\equiv zma+ynb\!\!\pmod{\!mn},\ \color{#c00}{\rm\ by}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix} \color{#0a0}z & \color{#0a0}y\\ \color{#0a0}{-n} & \color{#0a0}m\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} m & ma\\ n & nb\end{bmatrix} \equiv
\begin{bmatrix} d & zma+ynb\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\! \pmod{\!mn}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\  $$

But $\,\color{#0af}{zm} = d-yn\,\Rightarrow\, dx = \color{#0ad}{zm}a+ynb = da- yn(\color{#b0f}{a-b})\ \pmod{\!mn},\,$ so cancelling $\,d\,$ yields the claimed result ([recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) that $\,d\mid \color{#b0f}{a\!-\!b}\,$ is necessary for the original system to be solvable).

This is a special case of reduction to *Hermite normal form*, which is performable using the *fractional* extended Euclidean algorithm, as explained by an example at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just do not get the matrix part (the equivalence $dx\equiv zma+ynb$) and where comes $a\equiv b\pmod{d}$ in use?

Comment: @cal Reducing the original system $\!\bmod d\,$ yields $\,a\equiv x\equiv b,\,$ so $\,a\equiv b\pmod{\!d}\,$ is a necessary condition for a solution to exist (it's also sufficient as the proof shows). Row $1$ in the  matrix congruence means $\,\color{#0a0}z\,$ times $mx\equiv ma$ plus $\,\color{#0a0}y\,$ times $\,nx\equiv nb\,$ yields $\,dx\equiv zma+ynb,\,$ by $\,d = zm+yn\ \ $

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for your time.

Comment: @cal You might find simpler the [direct proof of the General Easy CRT formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242).