# Why is the solution to $8x \equiv 9 \pmod {15} $ unique?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, equivalence-relations

We can solve $8x \equiv 9 \pmod {15} $ by multiplying both sides by $8^{-1} \equiv 2 \pmod {15}$, getting $x \equiv 3 \pmod {15}$ so $x=3$. I know that the multiplicative inverse of a number is unique; but I am struggling conceptually to justify why this is a unique solution to $8x \equiv 9 \pmod {15} $. How can we show that there exists no other solution for x here?

Comment: Your argument already shows this.  You assumed $x$ was a solution to $8x\equiv 9 \mod 15$, and then proved using that assumption that $x$ must satisfy $x\equiv 3 \mod 15$.

Comment: If $8x \equiv 8y \pmod {15}$, then $8(x-y) \equiv 0 \pmod {15}$.  But $8$ is not a zero divisor in $\Bbb Z / 15 \Bbb Z$ (that's why it has an inverse), so $8(x-y) \equiv 0 \pmod {15} \Rightarrow x-y \equiv 0 \pmod {15} \Rightarrow x \equiv y \pmod {15}$.  This proof is slightly more general than yours because it doesn't require $8$ to have an inverse, just that it not be a zero divisor.  Of course, in a finite commutative ring, the two conditions are equivalent.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the solution is *not* unique. It is only unique modulo $15$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recall $ $ "solutions are unique $\!\bmod n$" means that if $x_1\,$
is a solution then every other solution $x_2$
is congruent to it $\,x_2\equiv x_1\pmod{\!n}\,$ or, equivalently,  solutions of $\,8x=9\,$ are unique in $\,\Bbb Z_{15}$]

The proof uses only *existence* (not *uniqueness*) of inverses, i.e. suppose $\,a'\,$ is *some* inverse of $\,a.\,$ Scaling $\,ax\equiv b\,$ by $\,a'\,$ yields $\,x\color{#c00}{\equiv a'b}.\,$ Uniqueness follows *immediately:* if $\,x_1,x_2\,$ are roots then $\,x_1\color{#c00}{\equiv a'b\equiv} x_2\,$ (which implictly exploits the fact that congruence, like equality, is an *equivalence relation* so it is *transitive*, i.e. $\,x_1\color{#c00}{\equiv y}\equiv x_2\,\Rightarrow\, x_1\equiv x_2)$.

---

*Existence* also follows immediately since scaling an equation or congruence by a *unit (invertible)* is an *invertible* operation so it yields an *equivalent* equation or congruence. Thus the above scaling is reversible: scaling $\,x\equiv a'b\,$ by $\,a\,$ yields $\,ax\equiv b,\,$ so $\,a'b\,$ is indeed a root. Summarizing

$${\rm if}\ \ \ a'a \equiv 1 \equiv aa'\ \ \ {\rm then}\ \ \  ax\equiv b\iff x\color{#c00}{\equiv a'b}\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ That the proof uses only the *existence* (not *uniqueness*) of some inverse $\,a'\,$ of $\,a\,$  is a point  often misunderstood, perhaps because some (very) popular textbooks mislead students by wrongly claiming that $\,x\,$ is unique because inverses of $\,a\,$ are unique, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3486032/242).

Though it is completely obvious with hindsight, it is often overlooked that uniqueness is an immediate consequence of an explicit solution $\,x\equiv\, \ldots\,$ (as in the direction $(\Rightarrow)$ above). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15465/242) for further discussion of another textbook example (additive case). [Another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4750426/242) occurred here a couple weeks ago.

The above shows that [scaling a congruence by a unit (invertible) yields an equivalent congruence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3461547/242) This is the congruence analog of a fact that is well know for equations, e.g. scaling a polynomial equation to an equivalent equation that is monic (lead coefficient $= 1),\,$ e.g. choosing *monic* minimal polynomials, or [unit-normalized polynomial gcds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3009888/242) in polynomial rings $\,k[x]$.

Comment: That scaling a congruence yields another true congruence is the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).  Congruences, like equality, are equivalence relations, so we can work with congruences in much the same way as we do equations, esp. since they are compatible with addition and multiplication (by the Congruence Sum & Product Rules). So we can think of congruences as generalized equations (they can be reified as equations when one learns about quotient rings, [here $\,\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z_m)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242)

Answer (score -1):

The question was originally written with solution
$x=3$.  It has now been edited to read $x \equiv 3$

The following refers to the question as it was originally asked with x=3, which technically refers specifically and exactly to only 3.

It's not.  For example, $x= 18$ is also a solution.
In fact $x=3+ 15n$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$ are also solutions.

Unless you meant the entire equivalence class {3 + 15n} in which case our answers are the same.

Comment: Hmmm, am I missing something?  There are two other comments suggesting I'm incorrect.

Comment: The tacit assumption is that we're looking at elements in $\Bbb Z / 15 \Bbb Z$.  In that ring, all of your proposed solutions are identical.

Comment: Uniqueness of roots of $f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{m}\,$ means if $x_1,x_2$ are roots then $\,x_1\equiv x_2\pmod{m},\,$ i.e. the roots are equal in $\Bbb Z_m.\,$ It's best to delete this answer to avoid further confusion.

Comment: It’s not mod 3. It should technically be $x\equiv 3 \mod 15$ or $x=[3]_{15}$, but it’s tacitly understood what they’re trying to show.

Comment: No, $\,x\pmod{\!3}\,$ is incorrect notation (cf. [comments here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4754655/242)).  When working with *congruence relations* the correct way to express the solution is $\,x\equiv 3\pmod{\!15}$

Comment: Oops, my comment had a typo.  I meant  $x=3$ is incorrect notation.  
I meant to suggest your correct notation $x \equiv 3$ or even $x \equiv 3 (mod 15)$

My previous comment simply used the wrong tag.  pmod instead of equiv.

Comment: About deleting my answer- students and people come to mathSE with a wide variety of different levels of mathematical understanding.  Most of the participants are graduate level and above.  However, many undergraduate students and a few high school students come here.  They will be significantly confused by BillDubuque 's answer.  Unit's, monic minimal poly's gcd's, etc. particularly.  Sometimes a simpler answer is useful particularly for students at earlier levels.